# Implementing a delegate to enable a modal view to pass data back to a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates

I am trying to implement a delegate to enable a modal view to pass data back to a UIViewController.

I have two view controllers, my main UIViewController and the modal.  Using the code below, the [delegate translationTextEntered:@"Test"]; doesn't affect the main screen (i.e. 'translationTextEntered' never gets called)

## My Main Controller

This contains a method to be called when the modal has the user's value:

***MainViewController.h***

```
- (void)translationTextEntered:(NSString *)txt;
```

***MainViewController.m***

```
- (void)translationTextEntered:(NSString *)text
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    _text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , text];
}
```

## My Modal Controller

This contains a UITableView which contains the delegate and, when an item is selected, should trigger the delegate callback.

***SuggestionViewController.h***

```
@protocol SelectTranslationDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)translationTextEntered:(NSString *)text;
@end

@interface SuggestionViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SelectTranslationDelegate>
{
    id<SelectTranslationDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak)id delegate;
```

***SuggestionViewController.h***

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ...      
    [delegate translationTextEntered:@"f"];

}
```

Comment: Do you actually assign `MainViewController` as the delegate to `SuggestionViewController`?

Comment: Hi Paul. Could you expand on this with an example please? My modal does UIViewController : <SelectTranslationDelegate>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import "SuggestionViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <SelectTranslationDelegate>

// - (void)translationTextEntered:(NSString *)txt;  <- Not required
```

The declaration of `- (void)translationTextEntered:(NSString *)txt;` is not required because you say that you conform to the `SelectTranslationDelegate` protocol (The bit between the `<`/`>`)

**MainViewController.m**

```
// The method where you instantiate SuggestionViewController
{
     // .. do your work

     SuggestionViewController *suggestionViewController = [[SuggestionViewController alloc] init];

     suggestionViewController.delegate = self; // <- This is the missing line

     [self presentModalViewController:suggestionViewController animated:YES];
     // [suggestionViewController release]; suggestionViewController = nil; // I'm assuming your using ARC

}
```

It should also be noted that your Modal view controller should not conform to `SelectTranslationDelegate` as this is most likely not your intention. So you declaration should be like:

```
@interface SuggestionViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

It is `MainViewController` that you want to respond to `translationTextEntered:` not `SuggestionViewController`. The `SuggestionViewController` is that one that makes the message call of `translationTextEntered:` on the `delegate`

Answer (score 0):

In your modal view controller in viewDidLoad or View WillAppear Include the sentence...

1. Create an object of your main view controoller... in view DidLoad...

   mainViewController *mainVC=[[mainViewController alloc] initwithnobname];...
2. Then set the sentence

   self.delegate=mainVC;

This is the thing that you need todo...